# How to enumerate a circular linked list using a for() expression?

Tags: c, list, collections, linked-list, containers

I've frequently used a linear linked list construct in C

```
typedef struct _node {
    ...node guts...
    struct _node *next
} node;
```

And the enumeration idiom

```
for (node *each = headNode; each != NULL; each = each->next)
```

I'm in a situation right now, where a circular list is attractive to me (e.g. the next of the last node is set to the headNode). Naively, I thought I'd using something similar to the `for` expression there, and the more I've stared at it, I think I've convinced myself you can't do something like that with a circular linked list.

It seems that no matter what kind of expression I come up with for the end conditional, I'll have the basic problem that I want said conditional to evaluate true the first time and false the second time the same node is encountered. I could do something with a loop side effect:

```
for (BOOL traversed = FALSE, node *each = headNode;
    traversed && each != headNode;
    traversed = TRUE, each = each->next)
```

But that definitely loses the elegance/simplicity of the null terminated list approach. Is there some trick of logic that's eluding me this late in the day?

Obviously I can use a while() construct, and maybe that's the only way to do it.

Comment: When you say you want to evaluate the first time, is this to ensure that you hit the body on the chance that the list consists of a single element such that headNode->next == headNode?

Comment: No, I deal with the single element circle separately.

Comment: Will you always set last node to the first one? Neither to the second and so on?

Comment: Great replies. I think @WhozCraig 's answer got the essence best.

Comment: That said, as I played around with this some more on my own and watched the answers roll in, I came to the same conclusion as @aib, that in reality a do {} while () was probably the most "obvious/easy to read" solution. I think the deception lay in believing that while the circular construct is ever so similar to the linear variant, that one change in pointer meaning really does fundamentally change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the following:

- An empty list means NULL for the starting point.
- The last node will be the one who's `next` pointer references your starting point, including a single-node list who's `next` pointer self-references.
- NO `next` pointers are NULL.

Then the following will do what you want using a tertiary expression as the incremental step.

```
// node* start comes from "somewhere'
for (node *p=start; p; p = (p->next==start ? NULL : p->next))
{
    // do something with p
}
```

Note: `p` will be NULL when this exits, one way or another; `start` will remain unchanged, and a NULL `start` is acceptable, as is a single-self-referencing node.

That said, I'd do this with a while-loop, but since you specifically asked for a for-loop you gets that =P.

Comment: I think given what I was after, this is probably the most terse realization. It reduces the lines of code to 1 (for the iteration) and requires no extra variables.

Comment: Hindsight a month later: I still feel like I cheated in this answer =P

Answer (score 1):

As you've already pointed out, any "current" pointer will simply cycle through the whole list, being no different on its second time around than the first.

Therefore you must use some other piece of information. As the simplest/smallest additional variable, a boolean, is too complex or inelegant by your admission, it can be inferred that this can't be done.

...unless you're already making use of some additional data, say a "prev" pointer that's initially null (in which case something very similar to your `traversed` example can be used).

For the record, I'd use a do...while:

```
struct _node *node = head;
do {
    ...
    node = node->next;
} while (node != head);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p = (pointer to some node)
pfirst = p
while true:
    do whatever with node (p)...
    p = p->next
    if (p==pfirst)  break
```

Note that this works for a one element list.

Comment: Oh yeah, add semicolons, if it's C.   (Been writing too much Python lately)

Answer (score 0):

The following re-arranged loop doesn't look too terrible:

```
for (node * n = head; ; )
{
    // process n

    if ((n = n->next) == head) { break; }
}
```

By the way, this only works for non-empty lists. Whatever your notion of emptiness is should be added as an initial check — unless you avoid that problem by having *dummy* head node (so that the empty list contains one node `n` with `n == head == n.next`, and in that case, you don't actually want to print the dummy at all and can use a genuine `for` loop (just put the above condition back into the loop statement)!

Comment: Did the OP want to have most of the logic in the condition of the for loop?  That's the impression I got, otherwise, why not just use a while loop?

Comment: @user1161318: `while` loops are ugly. I find that people who use them tend to litter the scope. I support clean loops for clean people.

Comment: Yes, I was curious if there was a for() approach to it, I can do a two variable while().

Comment: @KerrekSB: Although I disagree with you on the while, I love that line: "Clean loops for clean people". ROFL!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not just to loop a chain. It is not beautiful itself. How do you check you don't loop at the second element of the chain and so on?

If we have a notion of a `head` then we should hold a pointer to a `head` in each node or have it static. Also, instead of looping to the head, we should have special flag.